# defaultdict with tuple as the key, how to set default value in the event key isn't found

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, defaultdict

Let's say I have a `defaultdict` in the following form:

```
theta = defaultdict(float)
```

The key consists of a tuple of strings i.e. `(label, word)`, and the associated value is the probability that the given word fits the given label (part of speech tagging).

For example, the word 'stand' could be a noun or a verb. So I could do something like:

```
theta[('NOUN', 'stand')] = 0.4
theta[('VERB', 'stand')] = 0.6
theta[('ADJ', 'stand')] = 0.0
```

and so on for the remaining parts of speech labels.

What I need to do is have the dictionary return a value of 1 by default if it is invoked with a word that it does not contain and the associated label is 'NOUN', and return 0 for all other associated labels.  For example:

```
value = theta[('NOUN', 'wordthatdoesntexist')]  # this should be 1
value = theta[('VERB', 'wordthatdoesntexist')]  # this should be 0
```

How can I do this? Can I do it in the initialization step, using lambda? Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A defaultdict can't do that; the default factory doesn't have access to the key. You'd have to write your own dict subclass, using the `__missing__` hook dicts look for when you try to access a missing key:

```
class SomeAppropriateName(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def __missing__(self, key):
        val = 1.0 if key[0] == 'NOUN' else 0.0
        # Uncomment the following line if you want to add the value to the dict
        # self[key] = val
        return val
```

Comment: You need some sort of check word 'word exists' in there, at least in pseudocode.

Comment: @pvg: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying that I need an explicit check to handle the `key in self` case? `__missing__` doesn't get called for that case.

Comment: On re-reading it, I guess what I mean is 'word does not exist' is not well  defined. Does it mean 'does not exist as part of any key' or 'this part-of-speech/word pair does not exist'? But looks like the person asking sorted it out.

Comment: @pvg: Good point. If `('VERB', 'foo')` is already present as a key with value `0.5`, it might be a bad thing for accesses to `('NOUN', 'foo')` to default to `1.0`. I think figuring out the right thing to do would require more context than we have, and probably more context than the dict has.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `setdefault()` method of `dict`:

```
d.setdefault(u, int(u[0] == "NOUN"))
```

If `u` is found in `d`, then setdefault returns `d[u]`. Otherwise, it is inserted in the dict, with the value provided as second argument.